# Javascript key value from ajax string

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a string returned from php ajax page like this:

```
$returnString = "firstName=" . $row['firstName'] . "&lastName=" 
  .$row['lastName'] . "&address=" . $row['address'] . "&province_id=" 
  .$row['province_id'] . "&city_id=" . $row['city_id'];
```

so on my calling page I get the string returned to :

`var newCompleteString = this.responseText;`

I am trying to figure out the best way to parse the string into a key: value array

Comment: Is this what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/340760

Comment: Split from `&` that will build an array for each something=value. You can then loop through them and split them from `=` creating a new array. `array[0]` will = to the property and `array[1]` will = to the value

Comment: Example - https://jsfiddle.net/wgzrss0d/

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems to be basically the same as parsing the query string.

See this question [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/340760)

```js
const getParams = query => {
  if (!query) {
    return { };
  }

  return (/^[?#]/.test(query) ? query.slice(1) : query)
    .split('&')
    .reduce((params, param) => {
      let [ key, value ] = param.split('=');
      params[key] = value ? decodeURIComponent(value.replace(/\+/g, ' ')) : '';
      return params;
    }, { });
};

console.log(
  getParams('firstName=first&lastName=last&address=addr&province_id=322&city_id=11')
);
```